# How to restrict access to routes in react-router-dom based on session?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, flask-login

I have a React front-end and Python back-end with user session management using flask-login's **HttpOnly Session Cookies**. How can I **restrict react-router-dom** routes based on this type of session management? I've created a *ProtectedRoute* component:

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authenticated: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props
        return (
            <Route
                {...props}
                render={props => (
                    this.state.authenticated ?
                        <Component {...props} /> :
                        <Redirect to='/login' />
                )}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Is it possible to set `this.setState({authenticated: true})` based on the existing session?

Answer (score 3):

Why not pass `authenticated` (or `isEnabled`in my example) as a prop? `ProtectedRoute` will rerender when its props change. This is what I use in my React applications:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({isEnabled, ...props}) => {
    return (isEnabled) ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And then you can just use this like so:

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" isEnabled={isAuthenticated()} />
```

Comment: But what should isAuthenticated() do? I can't find how to get the session state from the React app, without making constant calls to the flask API. The Cookie is HttpOnly, so I can't access it via code wither.

Comment: `isAuthenticated` is just a function from your session management that returns true or false depending on if the session is valid or not. It could check if some cookie exists, or if a JWT is valid. Can be anything. Normally, you shouldn't have to call an API all the time to check your session.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I was looking for the same thing. Here's my `routes.js` file:

```
import auth from './services/auth'

const PrivateRoute = ({isAuthenticated, ...props}) => {
  return (isAuthenticated) ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>;
};

class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: false
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      auth.get('')
      .then( async (response) => {
        const status = await response.status
        if (status === 200) {
          this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
        } else {
          this.setState({isAuthenticated: false})
        }
      })
      .catch( async (error) => console.log(error))
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/" component={() => "barra"}/>
                <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/home" component={() => "home"}/>
                <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/profile" component={() => "profile"}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
    };
}
```

And `auth` import is:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const auth = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth"
})

export default auth;
```

So, basically I have a Flask app with Flask-Login running on another local server (with CORS enabled THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT) and if 200 is returned, user on react is authenticated.